# C# async operation not waiting wp8.1

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, nested, frontend

Hello I can't figure out why this async operation doesn't wait

```
private async void scroller_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLoadingMore)
            return;
        if (scroller.VerticalOffset > scrollContent.ActualHeight - (Frame.ActualHeight + 300))
            await LoadMoreItems();
    }
    bool isLoadingMore = false;
    private async Task LoadMoreItems()
    {
        isLoadingMore = true;
        try
        {
            List<Items> itemsList = await App.ServiceClient.GetItems("bananas");//<-------Doesn't wait
            foreach (Items in itemsList)
                listView.Items.Add(c);
        }
        catch { }
        isLoadingMore = false;
    }
```

And this is the backend call with another async task

```
public async Task<List<Items>> GetItems(string selector)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(myUrl),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        };
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        List<Items> items = null;
        var task = await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(
            async (s) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string Result = await s.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (s.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(Result);
                }
                catch
                { }
            });
        return items;
    }
```

The problem is the nested awaits or in the scoll view.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115580/async-await-not-waiting) but I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] (specifically "Minimal" part). So far `async void` looks suspicious - most likely your expectations of expected behavior are different from fire-and-forget.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is `async void`, so this will never be awaited by the UI, if you can't handle multiple `ViewChanged`events you have two options:

1-Disable the scroller while there is an async call executing:

```
private async void scroller_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    scroller.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        if (isLoadingMore)
            return;
        if (scroller.VerticalOffset > scrollContent.ActualHeight - (Frame.ActualHeight + 300))
            await LoadMoreItems();
    }
    finally{ scroller.Enabled = true; }
}
```

2-Don't execute the code if there is another event handler running:

```
bool runnning = false

private async void scroller_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(running)
        return;

    runnning = true;
    try
    {
        if (isLoadingMore)
            return;
        if (scroller.VerticalOffset > scrollContent.ActualHeight - (Frame.ActualHeight + 300))
            await LoadMoreItems();
    }
    finally{ running = false; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the List<Items> itemsList, it doesn't await to complete the Backend call and continuoes to the foreach where it gets null reference excetion

Comment: Hmmm, nearly 100% sure, if that's the problem is because the async lambda, it's the same as using TaskFactory.StartNew and Task.Run, the StartNew will not wait if the lambda is async and the Run will, the difference is that Run Unwraps the task for you, so maybe if you do this it will wait: `var task = await client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(theLambda).Unwrap()`. Here is more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917%28v=vs.110%29.aspx