# Async not waiting for await

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin and the coroutines. However I want to use it to initialize the Android ThreeTen backport library which is a long running task. I'm using the Metalab Async/Await Library ([co.metalab.asyncawait:asyncawait:1.0.0](https://github.com/metalabdesign/AsyncAwait)).

This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val application = this

    async {

        //non-blocking initialize ThreeTen
        await { AndroidThreeTen.init(application) }

        //initialize UI on UI thread which uses the ThreeTen library
        initUI()

    }
}
```

Now I have the problem that the library is not initialized when initializing the UI. From my understanding `initUI` shouldn't be called before `AndroidThreeTen.init` is called.

Comment: You should load the UI first then data second (or sooner in the background): http://stackoverflow.com/a/43151714/882912 Otherwise you freeze up your UI while you load the data. That way you can show a progress bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you should not use Kotlin coroutines for that.

The long answer is that your code needs AndroidThreeTen to be initialised *before* you initialise your UI, so you have to *wait* for `AndroidThreeTen.init` to finish before trying to invoke `initUI` anyway. Because of that inherent need to wait, there is little reason to overcomplicate your code. Coroutines are not magic. They will not make waiting for something that takes a lot of time somehow faster. `AndroidThreeTen.init` will take the same amount of time with coroutines or without them.

You should just write your code like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val application = this

    AndroidThreeTen.init(application)
    initUI()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the one hand you are right, it adds nothing to the performance. On the other hand I still don't understand why my code doesn't work. Is it [like here in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115580/async-await-not-waiting?rq=1) because of void which is bad practice?

Comment: That would be a question that authors of Metalab Async/Await Library might be able to answer. If you were using `kotlinx.coroutines`, then you could write it like that and it would work https://gist.github.com/elizarov/0b3e3386d304478368b3eb0380b6f25a